# Sequelize "raw = true" changes json model attribute name with dot

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have Content model and it has many sub ContentImage item, like this;

```
const content = await db.Content.findOne({
    where: {
        permalink: req.params.permalink
    },
    include: [{
        model: db.ContentImages
    }]
    raw: true
});
```

As you know `raw:true` covert SequelizeInstance to Object model. I have some problem in this point.

If I use `raw:true`, json model show me like this;

```
{
  "id": 4706,
  "name": "Content Title",
  "content": "Content detail",
  "t_content_images.id": 7633,
  "t_content_images.content_id": 4706,
  "t_content_images.image": "content-image-1.jpg",
  "t_content_images.order_no": 1
}
```

Because of expressjs, I need like this model instead of SequelizeInstance;

```
{
  "id": 4706,
  "name": "Content Title",
  "content": "Content detail",
  "t_content_images": {
    "id": 7633,
    "content_id": 4706,
    "image": "content-image-1.jpg",
    "order_no": 1
  }
}
```

Another problem, I have multiple content image and if I use like above first sample, it returns me just first content image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking about it a bit backwards - when you use `raw: true` it *doesn't* convert it from a JSON object to a Model Instance.

If you think of how SQL results are structured, they always come back flat. This means that for joins where you have one base record linked to multiple children (`Content -< ContentImages` in this case) then the SQL results will repeat the info for the base record for each of the children. Sequelize will parse this into a JSON object, which is what you are seeing in the first example in your question. If you leave out `raw: true` then it will take it a step further and parse it into an instance of your model. You can then call `Model.toJSON()` to get a JSON representation of the parsed object.

Given the above, if you are fetching lots of children then it can be more efficient to get the data into two queries instead of one so you don't have to send the repeating data to the client.

Comment: "You can then call Model.toJSON() to get a JSON representation of the parsed object." this is solved my problem. It converted SequelizeInstance to JSON Object. Thanks for your time.